# Relative sliders to all total 100

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three sliders which all need to total 100. I'd like each slider to be reactive to each other, much in the same way as this JS implementation at https://jsfiddle.net/x4wcn3m8/

Converted to Dart so far:

```
updateWeight({double value, String metric}) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> sliders = [
      {'type': 'strength', 'value': 0.50},
      {'type': 'agility', 'value': 0.30},
      {'type': 'speed', 'value': 0.20},
    ];

    double _sumOfSliderValues = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
      _sumOfSliderValues = _sumOfSliderValues + sliders[i]['value'];
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < sliders.length; j++) {
      if (sliders[j]['value'] != _sumOfSliderValues) {
        sliders[j]['value'] = (sliders[j]['value'] / _sumOfSliderValues) * 100;
      }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to convert this JS to Dart but am not succeeding or even sure if this is the correct approach in Dart. Can anyone shed any light on the best way to accomplish this slider effect?

Comment: I check the JS implementation link you provide, there is some case that total is not 100 (maybe 98 or 99). Is it expected?

Comment: If I could get it to total to 98/99 that would be great

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to know that Flutter Dart is all in `Widget`. So you have to build your slider layout in Widget which I haven't seen in your code. All layout and controller must be defined in Dart code.

Second you must know what is `StatefullWidget` and `StatelessWidge`. I suggest you can study them first before continue.

Finally, I try to build a simple StatefullWidget using the code you provide.

```
class SliderTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SliderTestState createState() => _SliderTestState();
}

class _SliderTestState extends State<SliderTest> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> sliders = [
    {'type': 'strength', 'value': 50.0},
    {'type': 'agility', 'value': 30.0},
    {'type': 'speed', 'value': 20.0},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Slider(
                value: sliders[0]['value'],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      sliders[0]['value'] = value;
                      _updateWeight();
                    },
                  );
                },
                max: 100.0,
                min: 0.0,
              ),
              Text(sliders[0]['value'].toInt().toString()),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Slider(
                value: sliders[1]['value'],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      sliders[1]['value'] = value;
                      _updateWeight();
                    },
                  );
                },
                max: 100.0,
                min: 0.0,
              ),
              Text(sliders[1]['value'].toInt().toString()),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Slider(
                value: sliders[2]['value'],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      sliders[2]['value'] = value;
                      _updateWeight();
                    },
                  );
                },
                max: 100.0,
                min: 0.0,
              ),
              Text(sliders[2]['value'].toInt().toString()),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _updateWeight() {
    double _sumOfSliderValues = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
      _sumOfSliderValues = _sumOfSliderValues + sliders[i]['value'];
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < sliders.length; j++) {
      if (sliders[j]['value'] != _sumOfSliderValues) {
        sliders[j]['value'] = (sliders[j]['value'] / _sumOfSliderValues) * 100;
      }
    }
  }
}
```